# Stop UISearchDisplayController from showing empty cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've implemented a UISearchDisplayController on a fairly standard tableview (same datasource for table + search). The problem I am having is when the results don't fill the screen there are "pseudo" rows below the actual results.

I was able to set the background color, but can't find a good way to suppress these rows/separators. They seem decoupled from my numberOfRowsInSection: delegate response.

If I set the searchResultsTableView.separatorColor (green) it only changes the actual results rows.

I was able to change separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorNone, but then I have to manually recreate the separators on the actual results and there are edge cases (like the selection color covers up my view).

Is there a clean way to hide the rows pointed out in the attached screenshot?

[image]

Comment: FYI - The solution is the same as for any table view. This being in a search controller is irrelevant.

Comment: Hmm. My regular table views do not show extra "cells" like this. Is the default behavior different (or do searchTableViews not inherit some config the way plain tableviews do from a storyboard)?

Comment: Any standard `UITableView` in plain style will show blank rows below your last actual row if your real rows don't fill the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably implement this delegate method for the Search Display Controller:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{
    UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
    footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [tableView setTableFooterView:footer];
}
```

This will make those last few rows disappear. You can of course do this in any other method you choose. For example, you can do this in `viewDidLoad` of a UIViewController if you want the same effect on a normal UITableView.

Comment: One last problem is the final row separator (between the actual rows, and the background) is now "temperamental". It doesn't show on first load, but does if I highlight-then-deselect or select and tap back.

Comment: That sounds like it could be an issue with your custom cells, or some other code.