# Search Bar and Search Display Controller not showing results after search

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, uisearchbar, uistoryboard

I am currently trying to figure out why a Search Bar and Search Display Controller is not displaying results after the user provides input.

1.) I'm very confident that the delegates and everything is configured correctly

2.) I have everything set up so I can see the console `NSLog` the data being reutrned

3.) This does not seem to produce anything:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}
```

4.) Data is added to `NSMutableArray` but just displays blank space

Other relating questions, there appears to be blank space at the bottom of these cells, why? Furthermore, besides `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` is there a way to detect when the search view/mode is dismissed? I have to change the status bar colour...

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

More code:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSString *authorizedSearch = [searchBar.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"search=%@",authorizedSearch];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"blahblahblah/search.php"]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if(conn) {
            NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
        }else{

        }


    return YES;
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data{
    NSString *ret = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"DATA: %@", ret);
    NSArray *objectArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [resultsJson addObject:objectArray];
    [resultsJson addObject:@"1"];
    NSLog(@"results: %@",resultsJson);
    NSLog(@"count: %i",[resultsJson count]);

}
```

Comment: Post some source code?

Comment: what do you want to see more of? @onnoweb

Answer (score 0):

What does your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` look like?

Are you using:

`[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

or:

`[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Seems like there shouldn't be a difference, but I think there is.

Are you setting data properly for each backing store?

---

Could there be a race condition on results arriving and attempting to render them?

---

If you're sure the data is correct, could it be an autolayout (or similar) issue mashing up the frame? I've had that happen frequently and fix by adjusting everything in: `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

---

See here for a *possible* reason on blank spaces at the bottom:
[Stop UISearchDisplayController from showing empty cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434610/stop-uisearchdisplaycontroller-from-showing-empty-cells)